# Custom post type permalink issue

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

I already have a 'custom structure' for my 'Posts', e.g. `example.com/newsarchive`, so my 'Posts' follow: `example.com/newsarchive/welcometonovember`

Now I am expanding and created a new custom post type called: `Movies`

I want the permalinks for these items to be:

```
example.com/moviearchive/favouritemoviepost
```

However, at the moment I am getting:

```
example.com/newsarchive/moviearchive/favouritemoviepost
```

How can I change that?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not calling flush_rewrite_rules() in your activation hook, try it.